# Extension installation error: Please install nodejs 5+ and npm before continuing installation

Tags: python, node.js, windows

While trying to embed bokeh plots in jupyterlab. I used their recommended codes (below)

`jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager, jupyter labextension install @bokeh/jupyter_bokeh`

> Error: File "", line 1
>       jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
>               ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Then using jupyterlab extension manger I again tried to install `jupyterlab-manager` but then `Error: Please install nodejs 5+ and npm before continuing installation. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website.`

I then tried to install nodejs and then wheel using `pip install nodejs and npm` but to no avail. Same error was repeated

> Error: Please install nodejs 5+ and npm before continuing installation. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website

I installed bokeh using `pip install jupyter-bokeh` and I am using jupyterlab. I am not using conda. And operating system is windows

I am new to programming. Your step-by-step solution will be high appreciated.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: doesnt work either with this download

Answer (score 3):

1. Install node.js first, either through conda or brew if you are using
   a mac.
2. Verify installation.
3. Install Extension

I

```
brew install node
node -v
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

Answer (score 1):

You said your OS is windows, so install Node.js using the installer from https://nodejs.org/en/ .

I would restart the machine just to be sure.

Then try again to install the extension.

For more help about jupyter lab extensions read the official docs at: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html .

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager, jupyter   labextension install @bokeh/jupyter_bokeh
```

has a stray comma in it and I think other errors.  Please follow instructions here on how to install ipywidgets

https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html

After installing ipywidgets to also install bokeh follow these instructions

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/installation.html#installation

I think if you want to use bokeh in jupyter widgets ipywidgets must be
installed before the bokeh install, but I'm not sure.
I know the following
instructions work

https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_proxy_widget/blob/master/README.md